# How do i include the marker which is in my local directory

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: startLocation ,
            icon : 
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
```

in the icon option : I want to put there my downloaded marker icon. Which is in my public/img directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: startLocation ,
        icon :image 
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
```

here you are !

Comment: I put it in my public directory in my local project. i didn't get it from an online source.

Comment: you can change this link as  {{public_path('\your folder\your icon name.ico')}}

Comment: var image = " {{public_path('\your folder\your icon name.ico')}}"